# Property that gets value from a query doesn't get persisted EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

This my class:

```
public class BonDeReceptionFournisseur
{
    private readonly BigSoftContext bigSoftContext;

    public BonDeReceptionFournisseur()
    {
    }

    private BonDeReceptionFournisseur(BigSoftContext bigSoftContext)
    {
        this.bigSoftContext = bigSoftContext;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Decimal? PrixTotaleTTc { get; set; }

    private Decimal? PrixTotaleTTc2 => DetailsReceptions?.Sum(x => x.MontantTTc)
        ?? bigSoftContext.Set<DetailsReceptionFournisseur>()
        .Where(x => x.IdBonReception == Id).Sum(x => x.MontantTTc)
        ?? 0;
    public Decimal? PrixTotaleHt { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Boolean Confirmed { get; set; }
    public int FournisseurId { get; set; }
    public virtual Fournisseur Fournisseur { get; set; }
    public string GrossisteId { get; set; }

    public virtual Grossiste Grossiste { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DetailsReceptionFournisseur> DetailsReceptions { get; set; }
    public FactureFournisseur FactureFournisseur { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I want "PrixTotaleTTc" to get calculated from class "DetaislReceptionFournisseur". but I'm getting the error

> No backing field could be found for property 'BonDeReceptionFournisseur.PrixTotaleTTc2' and the property does not have a setter.

I followed Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors)

Comment: The error is about `PrixTotaleTTc2`, though and pretty straight forward about what the the problem is. If you want `PrixTotaleTTc` calculated, then you should add the information when and how you want it calculated.

Comment: Mark this property as `[NotMapped]`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i should have mentioned this but I wanted it mapped

Comment: @Fildor well if i write same code for PrixTotaleTTc It will get me the same error

Comment: Mapped to what? Property has no setter. How EF should load data from database into that property?

Comment: You can _either_ calculate it _or_ map it. You cannot have the cake _and_ eat it. What you _can_ do is for example "calculate it if empty". Is it that what you want?